# update-usbids: command not found, why?

Tags: xubuntu, 20.10

What should I install for the `update-usbids` command to be found?

I have:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Comment: @Rinzwind that doesn't exist; cf https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/usbutils/filelist with https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/usbutils/filelist   My system doesn't include it either as it's no longer provided by default  (also see https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/usb.ids/filelist ; it wasn't in *focal* either)

Comment: Hmm http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/update-usbids.8.html stops at 18.04 AH it became a systemd tool: https://tracker.debian.org/news/772418/accepted-usbutils-1008-1-source-into-experimental/

Comment: This onenhttp://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/general/usbutils.html

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I learned that `update-usbids` is obsolete on systemd based systems that's why not available.

PS: based on [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/update-usbids-command-not-found-why-4175693261/#post6238188) answer